# Rails: Using named_scope which triggers a MySQL "in"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, named-scope

**PROBLEM:**

I want to run a query which would trigger something like

```
select * from users where code in (1,2,4);
```

using a `named_scope`.

---

**WHAT I TRIED:**

This is for a single code:

```
named_scope :of_code, lambda {|code| {:conditions => ["code = ?", code]}}
```

I tried something like

```
named_scope :of_codes, lambda {|codes| {:conditions => ["code in ?", codes]}}
```

and sent

```
user.of_codes('(1,2,4)')
```

it triggers 
`select * from users where code in '(1,2,4)'` which raises a MySQL error because of the extra quotes.

**PS:** *Ideally I would like to send* `user.of_codes([1,2,4])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work just find and not expose you to the SQL injection attack:

```
named_scope :of_codes, lambda { |codes|
  { :conditions => ['code in (?)', codes] }
}

User.of_codes([1, 2, 3])
# executes "select * from users where code in (1,2,3)"
```

If you want to be a little more slick, you can do this:

```
named_scope :of_codes, lambda { |*codes|
  { :conditions => ['code in (?)', [*codes]] }
}
```

Then you can call it either with an `Array` (as above): `User.of_codes([1, 2, 3])`, or with a list of code arguments: `User.of_codes(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Your second solution won't not work when passed an Array. Instead of `[*codes]` use `codes.flatten`

Comment: Are you saying to use `['code in (?)', [*codes].flatten]`? Unless you're passing non-`Array`s and `Array`s in the same call, the `[*]` will do the flattening for you. I suppose if you want to be able to do `User.of_codes(1, 2, [3, 4])` then you would need `#flatten`, but that seems awkward.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach would be to use a hash for conditions instead of an array:

```
named_scope :of_codes, lambda { |*codes| { :conditions => { :code => codes } } }
```

This will work as expected.

```
User.of_codes(1, 2, 3) # => SELECT ... code IN (1,2,3)
User.of_codes(1) # => SELECT ... code IN (1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure when this support was added. It certainly works on all my Rails 2.3.x applications, but it might not work on older ones.

Answer (score 2):

you can try follwing

```
named_scope :of_codes, lambda {|codes| {:conditions => ["code in "+codes]}}
```

and

```
user.of_codes('(1,2,4)')
```

EDITED For SQL INJECTION PROBLEM USE

```
named_scope :of_codes, lambda {|codes| {:conditions => ["code in (?) ", codes]}}
```

and

```
user.of_codes([1,2,4])
```

Comment: Thanks Salil. I should have figured that out.. .

Comment: This will leave you open to SQL injection attacks. If it's *at all possible* that those codes will come from user input, you *must not* use this method.

Comment: @james:- this is my assumption that those codes will not come from user.

Comment: @james :- check my edited answer. hope that will not open injection attacks :)